# Source code not being received by Request Module

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am using Request Module to send a request to server. In response I am getting just few lines from page source not the whole page.

```
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://www.yellowpages.ae/c/advs/uae/web.html"

header = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
          'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
          'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,ml;q=0.7',
          'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
          'Connection': 'keep-alive',
          'Host': 'www.yellowpages.com',
          'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36'
          }
try:
    print("Present Link: ", url)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e)
except URLError:
    print("URL Error")
else:
    print(response.status_code)
    print("response is:", response.text)
```

**Output of page if i do not send header in request**
the output is is just this data while page source contains alot of text please check it and suggest me what i'm doing wrong.

```
Web at Yellowpages.ae
window.onload = markiconsLarge;
}
$create(Sys.Extended.UI.AutoCompleteBehavior, {"completionSetCount":12,"delimiterCharacters":"","id":"advs_autokey","minimumPrefixLength":2,"serviceMethod":"Getkeyword","servicePath":"../../../YpWebService.asmx","useContextKey":true}, null, null, $get("advs_txtkey"));
});
```

.
.
.
.
.

something like that unable to paste whole output as code. so its just part of it to make my point clear.

Will be grateful. Thanks

Comment: Why are you including all of those headers? If I do a simple `r = requests.get(url); print(r.text)` I get a full response back...

Comment: i also tried but what i'm getting for that  please see the edited question